# Quick Outline for JavaScript extremely slow in Eclipse Neon and Oxygen

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-neon, eclipse-oxygen, eclipse-2018-09

Whenever I type Ctrl-O when editing a large JavaScript file (1500 lines of code) in Eclipse Neon (4.6.3), it takes about 4 seconds until the Quick Outline box is shown, which is extremely annoying. It happens all the time (not only the first time). It works well for small files. This problem wasn't present in Eclipse Mars.

Is there any fix or opened bug regarding this?

**Edit:** It works better in Eclipse Oxygen, but there is still some lag.

**Edit:** The problem is still there in Eclipse 2018-09.